# Get Groups From Words

Tags: c#, regex

I'm struggling to write a reg-ex that can do the following:

```
Label1.Caption := Edit1.Text;
```

Must return 2x results e.g.:

```
Label1.Caption
Edit1.Text
```

So its everything where its a word (Like "Label1"), a dot (.) and a given set of words like "Caption", "Text" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([\w.]+)\s*:=\s*([\w.]+)
```

This regex is more flexible than what you specified. Something like `__hello...6 := oops` will also pass. If you need the restrict to the Identifier.Identifier format,

```
([A-Za-z_]\w*\.[A-Za-z_]\w*)\s*:=\s*([A-Za-z_]\w*\.[A-Za-z_]\w*)
```

Comment: `<nitpick>` The second solution won’t work with identifiers starting with á, ä, å, ... `</nitpick>` ☺